# How do i export .dmx animations using blender source tools?

Tags: animation, export, add-on

a) When I export mesh it exports giving warning https://i.stack.imgur.com/4QS2q.jpg ,but when I export animations I get error message https://i.stack.imgur.com/XhhQh.jpg. Software created an anims folder on specified location but it was empty. Blender file link :http://www.mediafire.com/download/ggm4tb1is5r10bt/ep.blend.

b) For exporting .dmx its mandatory to give address of folder containing resourcecompiler file. Do i give address for Dota 2 beta or Dota 2 test as i am interested in attaching particles to my custom ward mesh.